# PHP/MySQL - Changing Query on clicking a link

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very basic site (just learning this stuff) where I have the results for a hockey pool I do from [here](http://hockeypool.varanusweb.com). 
I want to build a page that lists the players and then when they click on a name, a page comes up with just that player's picks on it. You can see the kind of page I mean [here](http://hockeypool.varanusweb.com/view_picks_by_player.php).

THis page currently only shows one player, as I am using this query:

```
$q = "SELECT *, player_id, handle 
        FROM round_one 
  INNER JOIN players USING (player_id) 
       WHERE (player_id = 1)";
```

Right now I have it set just to return player_id 1, but I want it to do player_id 2, 3, 4 etc depending on what linked name they click on.

I have been reviewing some documentation on sort by columns queries when clicking on a column header, and am thinking this is sort of the approach I should be taking, but I just can't seem to figure out the correct way to do it.

Comment: how are your data tables structured?

Comment: Hi - my data is basically in two tables - one is called round_one where it has all the data for the player picks, and the other is players where I have the player name, id, etc. They are joined through the player_id field in the tables.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by passing a parameter to the view_picks_by_player.php page, and then PHP can pick up that parameter and generate content for the appropriate player.

For example, in the page where you select the player you want stats for you could have:

```
<a href='view_picks_by_player?id=player1'>Get Player 1's Stats!</a>
<a href='view_picks_by_player?id=player2'>Get Player 2's Stats!</a>
```

And then in the top of the view_picks_by_player.php page you could have:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM player_stats WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Obviously your SQL is structured differently, but this is just a quick way to show how you can pass a variable to the php page so it can generate different content dynamically.

For security, you'll want to validate that the user has not typed anything nasty into the URL as the 'id' before you use it in your SQL, but that's another topic...

Comment: You touched on it, but the simplest thing to do right off the bat is sanitize the id by throwing it in an if and checking is_int($id) and returning false if not, so that people can't do a simple injection hack.

Comment: Yeah, except that `is_int` will always fail.  From the docs, "To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use is_numeric().".  I personally check by converting to an integer and back again then verifying that it's the same, e.g. `strval($val) == strval(intval($val))`, because `is_numeric` allows more than just integers through.

Comment: Thank Dan for your response and help - and thanks to all the others for the validation issue help - all worked perfectly and I can see that all of this stuff will really help me down the road as well...thanks again.

Comment: I ran into a little snag on this - thought I had it, but when I tried to change the parameters to the ones I use it didn't work.  The column I use for the player's id # is 'player_id" so should I put that instead of id in my select statement so it reads $sql = "SELECT * FROM player_stats WHERE id = '$id'"; - should it be $sql = "SELECT * FROM player_stats WHERE player_id = '$id'";...and if so, would the $id query change? And I am assuming in the href statement is should be id=1, id=2, etc...is this correct. I am getting a 404 error on this now. thanks again.

Comment: Yes the SQL should use the field name you in your database just how you described it.  The PHP variable can really be named anything, so you can leave it as $id, or change it to something that makes more sense to you.

Comment: Hi Dan - Should the GET statement be $id = $_GET['id']; or $id = $_GET['player_id']; - I am assuming it is just ID since the player_id just needs to be in the SQL Query, correct? I am still getting a 404 error. I even tried to just put the url in the browser and am still getting the 404 error, so I am still doing something wrong on the page.